# Does the screen density is dpi or ppi?

Tags: android

I get my android phone screen density 240 dpi using DX Toolbox:

```
Screen density
240 DPI
```

but the screen density is PPI (pixels per inch) I known.

Which one can be used to describe the screen density?

Comment: http://blog.edwinevans.me/?p=131

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DPI and PPI is the same. Dots per inch vs <strike>points</strike> pixels per inch. Do not confuse DPI with dip (density independent pixels).

**Edit:**

I was suggested PPI means pixels per inch, which seem right.

Further reading ([from polish wikipedia](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppi)) suggests that DPI is incorrectly used in this context and it should be used in context of printing.

Also [point in typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29) is equal to 1/72 of an inch.